# How to use tzachar/cmp-tabnine in NvChad?

Tags: neovim, nvchad

This are the [installation instructions for tzachar/cmp-tabnine using Packer](https://github.com/tzachar/cmp-tabnine#install):

```
return require("packer").startup(
 function(use)
    use "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp" --completion
    use {'tzachar/cmp-tabnine', run='./install.sh', requires = 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'}
 end
)
```

And later, enable the plugin:

```
require'cmp'.setup {
 sources = {
    { name = 'cmp_tabnine' },
 },
}
```

There is also some [setup](https://github.com/tzachar/cmp-tabnine#setup).

This is the NvChad documentation for [adding a plugin](https://nvchad.github.io/config/Custom%20config#add-plugins), and for [overriding default plugin configuration](https://nvchad.github.io/config/Custom%20config#override-default-config-of-a-plugin).

This is what I've done:

```
-- NvChad/lua/custom/plugins/init.lua
return {
   ["tzachar/cmp-tabnine"] = {
      after = "cmp-path",
      config = function()
         require "custom.plugins.tabnine"
      end,
   },
}

-- NvChad/lua/custom/plugins/tabnine.lua
require('cmp_tabnine.config').setup({
   max_lines = 1000;
   max_num_results = 20;
   sort = true;
   run_on_every_keystroke = true;
   snippet_placeholder = '..';
   ignored_file_types = { -- default is not to ignore
           -- uncomment to ignore in lua:
           -- lua = true
   };
   show_prediction_strength = false;
})

-- NvChad/lua/custom/chardrc.lua
M.plugins = {
   override = {
      ["hrsh7th/nvim-cmp"] = {
         sources = {
            { name = "nvim_lsp" },
            { name = "luasnip" },
            { name = "buffer" },
            { name = "nvim_lua" },
            { name = "path" },
            { name = "cmp-tabnine" },
          },
      }
   }
}
```

There must be something I'm doing wrong. When I do `:PackerSync` nothing happens.

The developer of cmp-tabnine tzachar has said:

> Never used NvChad. But one issue that comes to mind is that you need to run the install.sh script.
> No Idea how to do that in NvChad.

Here is an [example configuration in NvChad](https://github.com/siduck/dotfiles/tree/master/nvchad/custom).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This type of problem _may_ be best answered by asking the plugin devs and/or community directly.

Comment: cmp-tabnine should be cmp_tabnine and you also need to add custom formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I've got tabnine working with my local nvchad version. Here's what I added to my custom configuration.

lua/custom/chardrc.lua

```
local pluginConfs = require "custom.plugins.configs"
local M = {}

M.plugins = {
  user = require "custom.plugins",
  override = {
    ["hrsh7th/nvim-cmp"] = pluginConfs.cmp,
    ["tzachar/cmp-tabnine"] = pluginConfs.tabnine
  }
}
```

lua/custom/plugins/configs.lua

```
local M = {}

M.cmp = function()
  return {
    formatting = {
      format = function(entry, vim_item)
        if entry.source.name == 'cmp_tabnine' and entry.completion_item.data ~= nil then
            vim_item.kind = string.format("%s %s", '', ' TabNine')
        else
          local icons = require("nvchad_ui.icons").lspkind
          vim_item.kind = string.format("%s %s", icons[vim_item.kind], vim_item.kind)
        end

        return vim_item
      end,
    },
    sources = {
      { name = "cmp_tabnine" },
      { name = "luasnip" },
      { name = "nvim_lsp" },
      { name = "buffer" },
      { name = "nvim_lua" },
      { name = "path" },
    },
  }
end

M.tabnine = function()
  return {
    max_lines = 1000,
    max_num_results = 5,
    sort = true,
    run_on_every_keystroke = true,
    show_prediction_strength = false
  }
end

return M
```

lua/custom/plugins/init.lua

```
-- custom/plugins/init.lua has to return a table
-- THe plugin name is github user or organization name/reponame
local pluginConfs = require "custom.plugins.configs"

return {
  ["tzachar/cmp-tabnine"] = {
     after = "nvim-cmp",
     run = "./install.sh",
     config = pluginConfs.tabnine
  },
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I think the OP is not around anymore to vote on/comment on/accept this answer, so have my upvote :)

Comment: ty! I hit this page while I was trying to get it working. Hopefully, it'll help others. :D